# How to directly open .m files with octave GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface, octave

My problem is with Octave on Windows.
I am trying to open an .m file with Octave GUI, but I don't want to run it immediatly.

Currently, when I do this, an Octave GUI window opens, as a Notepad++ window (which is empty?). This Octave window is already set to the path where my .m file was located.
Then, I have to click on "file-->open...--> myfile.m" to make the code appear in the editor tab. From there I can modify it (some parameters I want to change for example), or launch it directly.

Is there any way to directly get the file opened in Octave GUI (in the editor tab, without having to do "file-->open-->...")? Or a simple script.bat file to configure for doing this purpose?

Comment: Do you mean Octave should read your mind as to which file to open? What do you mean with “directly”?

Comment: “Currently, when I do this, an Octave GUI window opens...” do you mean that you interact somehow with the file in Windows Explorer, and want Octave to open up and load the file in its editor? But instead it opens up with an empty editor tab?

Comment: Ah sorry : I meant that when I double click on my .m file (in my case that's a program to calculate some physical parameters), the Octave GUI opened with an empty editor tab, and that's why I have to do the "file->open->"myfile.m"" procedure.
So, what I would like to have is : when I double click my .m file, Octave is opened and the .m file is loaded and appears in my GUI edidot tab.

Comment: I think what you want is the default behaviour. What Version and have you run the installer or do you run the portable Version? How are .m files handled in your Explorer? There is a menu Option foe this

Comment: When I check the properties of my .m file :
File Type : GNU Octave Script (.m)
Open with : Microsoft Windows Based Script Host (I can modify to select "Octave.vbs", but in that case it will not open at all)
I use "GNU Octave 4.4.0", but I don't know what you mean by "installer or portable version" ?

Comment: I can make it do that on 4.4.0 as well - installer version - looks like a potential race condition, and it will then open the .m file in notepad++ and show the octave GUI - even though preferences are set to open in the GUI - I cant make it do that in Octave 5.1, so it was potentially fixed in later versions

Comment: Sounds like you might have previously changed the File Associations settings in Windows so that `.m` files are associated with Notepad++ instead of Octave? I haven't run Windows in a while, but if you right-click a `.m` file, choose "Open With...", I think the dialog that comes up will have a checkbox where you can say "Always open with this program", and select Octave, and you'll go back to opening `.m` files with Octave.

Answer (score 0):

You must unistall the older version first. Then install the newer one. If you installed newer one first and then uninstalled the older one, then it will not work. So now you must uninstall and reinstall the newer one. Then the following will work.

> Select "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host" for .m files.
> It is usually located in C:\Windows\System32 and named as <wscript.exe>

Answer (score -1):

[GNU Octave - Bugs: bug #47696, Can't set Octave as default app...](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47696)

--> You have to select "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host" for .m files. Check whether the description changes to "GNU Octave Script".